# nullpointexception when i use those variables declared inside the scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I got the following code kind of inside of my <% %> in my jsp file.

Two problems here:

Why doesnt my breakpoint doesnt stop in those lines?

Why does have a nullpointerException happen when i use these variables somewhere inside my jsp like these <%=beneficiariesList%>. This value debugging in eclipse in the display view says " beneficiariesList cant be resolved" . For example tipoBeneciarioDatosClientes says the value which is "XXXX"

```
<% ...... bla bla bla

    String    tipoBeneficiarioDatosClientes = "XXXXX";
    String    beneficiariesList             = "XXXXX";
    if (null != polizaBean.xxxxx()  &&  !polizaBean.getTipoBeneficiario().isEmpty()) {
    tipoBeneficiarioDatosClientes = polizaBean.xxxxxx();

    if(tipoBeneficiarioDatosClientes.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxx")) {

        JSONArray beneficiaries      = JSONArray.fromObject(polizaBean.xxxxx());
        beneficiariesList = beneficiaries.toString(); 
    }
}

%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `NullPointerException` because variables which you are using inside **Scriptlets** `<% ... %>` are only available inside that scriplet.

If you want to declare variable which will be available in **Expressions** `<%= %>` you need to declare them inside a **Declations** block `<%! %>`.

From JSP 2.0 Specification :

> Declarations are used to declare variables and methods in the
>   scripting language used in a JSP page.
>   **...**
>   Declarations are initialized when the JSP page is initialized and are made
>   available to other declarations, scriptlets, and expressions.

Comment: Hi @marojbor,  but I got some others variables which are declared inside the scriptlet and they are working without no problem. The only difference that those variables get his value by an object class instead of string. For example: Stirng aaaa = PolizaBean.getIdentifierFullName();  I got not problems there there are not null point exceptions